# How to customize the Menu controller with menus having an images in iPad?

Tags: xcode, ipad, uimenucontroller

Iam developing an iPad application which includes UIMenuController, I integrated the Menu controller which shows my own titles. But I need to show images instead of titles in the Menu controller. Could anybody have a suggestion to implement that.

Thanks in advance